# Should a like/follow button in Symfony2 be a link or a form?

Tags: php, symfony, csrf

I am implementing a like/follow system on my **Symfony2** project, via AJAX.

I feel like the the button should be a form (for CSRF-purposes), but a link would be significantly easier to generate in the template, given the prevalence of the like button across the site.

**Can we protect links from CSRF attacks?**

**What are the industry best practices?**

Comment: You could always create a macro to generate the like buttons rather than needing to recreate the form each time. Then you could just call `{% from '..._macros.html.twig' import linkButton %}{{ linkButton(**url/params/etc**) }}`.

Comment: might be worth looking at [Nomaya's social bundle](https://github.com/nomayann/NomayaSocialButtonsBundle) and see how he does it.

Comment: good question, and I hope someone give a good answer. I always used "mini-forms" for post, so that the'll work with pure HTML (read phpunit) and CSRF; the flip of the coin, is that pages with tons of actions, like index, get a speed penalty for the form rendering engine. Maybe a macro for micro-form is the best? don't know.

Comment: I think you're on the right track - when I've had cases like this in the past, what I'll do is create an array of forms that are very simple; as in, they all post to the same location and don't even have any hidden fields besides the CSRF token; the ID of the field you want to change is posted in the URL (so for example, `/like/{id}`), and then you have a separate Controller route that handles that.